# Why am I getting an array with the name I assigned to a prop at index 0, and the actual prop I want to pass at index 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to put together a quick employee management app prototype in React (no Redux) and am totally stuck on passing the **employees** array from my parent component, App, to its direct child, OEView. App is a class component, OEView is a functional component. The employee data is being imported from a .js file in the src folder.

Here is App.js

```
import { Component} from 'react';
import OEView from './containers/OEView';
import {employeeData} from "./data";

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    employees: employeeData,
    user: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.checkUp();
  }

  checkUp = () =>{
    console.log(this.state)
  }


  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <OEView>employees = {this.state.employees}</OEView>
        </div>
    )

  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is OEView.js

```
import EmployeeCard from '../components/EmployeeCard';

const OEView = (props) => {

    console.log(props);

    function renderEmployees() {
        return props.employees.length > 0 ? props.employees.map(employee => {
          return (
            <div key={employee.id} >
              <EmployeeCard {...props} employee={employee} key={employee.employeeId}  />
            </div>
          )
        }): null
      }

      return (
        <div>
            
            {/* <div className="item">
            Employees
            </div>
            {renderEmployees()} */}
        </div>
      );
}
export default OEView;
```

Here is the result of the console.log on line 6 of OEview

```
{children: Array(2)}
children: Array(2)
0: "employees = "
1: (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

As you can see in the code there is also an employee card component, but it is currently commented out and is not part of the issue here. There may also be other issues with the renderEmployees function since it is a re-use of a render function I built when I learned React a year ago, but those are not the issue at hand.

**From the above you can see that the employee data I want to use in OEView is indeed being passed, but as the second item in an array, with the string "employees =" as the first item in the array. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: What's in data.js? Your answer depends on this line: `import {employeeData} from "./data";`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought about posting that too, but it is pretty long and I thought it would stop people from scrolling to the bottom of my question. Fortunately @sh.alawneh was able to answer without it.

Answer (score 0):

in the code here:

```
<OEView>employees = {this.state.employees}</OEView>
```

you are passing them as a children prop to the OEView component, and you can see that they are logged under the key `children` in the console.

**so to get it right and as you want, you should do it like the following**:

```
<OEView employees={this.state.employees} />
```

hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I feel dumb for getting stuck on such a small thing. In my defense I have been doing backend for the last 8 months. I guess I forgot more React than I thought in that time.